# The page is empty after deployed VueJS app to Firebase

Tags: firebase, npm, web-applications, vuejs2, web-deployment

I tried to deploy two apps in Google Firebase,

One is relatively simple, just a `App.vue` with a function which can passes info to the Firebase Database.

Another one is kind of complicated with several vue components and the use of vue-router.

I followed the same step for these two apps:

```
npm run build
firebase init
```

after answered some prompt (the current firebase tool I installed only asked me what service did I want (Hosting), what project you want to use(Firebase Project))

After that I configured both apps' firebase.json file in the same way:

```
{
"hosting": {
  "public": ""
}
}
```

the `dist` folder generated from `npm run build` didn't contain any html files for both apps, I think its weird so I didn't configure the path to `./dist`

after I ran `firebase deploy`, only that simplest app can display properly. Another one just blank page. My vue-router doesn't using History Mode, How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before building makes sure you have the `index.html` file.

Here is the correct configuration you've to put:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've also written a written an in-depth guide on [auto-deploying VueJS apps to Firebase hosting](https://coffeencoding.com/auto-deploy-vuejs-app-to-firebase-hosting-with-gitlab-cd/)

Comment: no buddy, I did exactly what you did.  Some of my components render, but some didnt.  There must be some other underlying issue here...